# What is Redis database index impact on performance

Tags: redis

Disclaimer: I've read lots of posts that claim using Redis databases being a bad idea, please lets not discuss that here.

I'm holding my customer's configuration in Redis DB with use of structured keys. However, I have to support several versions of my application and those have slightly different configurations, so I decided to store different versions in different databases. The main reason to uses different databases and not yet another layer of key structuring is the ability to flush a certain DB instantly instead of deleting the keys one at a time. And I need that when I decide to drop a version. 
Now, as versions emerge the upper and lower indexes will naturally climb as I add new versions and drop the older ones. Then, when I hit the upper index boundary, I have two alternatives: I could "reuse" the index I already abandoned or I can just add a new one. Obviously, reusing indexes requires some extra-management that I would like to avoid.

So, my question is the following: is there a performance/memory-wise difference between working in database range 5-15 and working in database range 2005-2025?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Received an answer on Redis reddit, posting here for reference:

> Hey,
>
> It depends on how pedantic you want to get in terms of
>   performance/memory impact but in short, basically not at all.
>
> Here is what happens in the SELECT command:

```
int selectDb(client *c, int id) {
     if (id < 0 || id >= server.dbnum)
         return C_ERR;
     c->db = &server.db[id];
     return C_OK; }
```

> Redis will then interact with c->db for any given command, and the
>   selection of the database is literally just an array lookup.
>
> As always you should test this yourself, but I don't see why it would
>   impact performance in any meaningful way.

https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/4wplmc/what_is_redis_database_index_impact_on_performance/d69b4z8